# Custom Boot animation slows, freezes and crashes phone

Tags: boot, boot-animation

I've created a custom boot animation:

1. Create animation with Blender, render all the frames 1080 x 1920, PNG.
2. Convert them to JPG.
3. Store frame 0 to 123 to folder `part0`, store frame 124 to folder `part1`.
4. Create `desc.txt` with content (every line ends with `<LF>`):

   ```
   1080 1920 24
   p 1 0 part0
   p 0 0 part1
   ```
5. Store all that into `bootanimation.zip` (mode: Store), almost 10 MB.
6. Copy it onto the SD card and copy it to `/system/media/` with TWRP.

When I reboot the phone, it displays the animation okay, but then slows down (still during the first loop), halts, and reboots after a few seconds.

Is there anything I've done wrong? The phone is a Fairphone 2, running Fairphone Open with the newest TWRP and encrypted data partition.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to shrink the frames by half (540*960) but leaving the description text as it was – it seems that it just was too much data.